# How to decode JPG file to the same bitmap on Android and Linux?

Tags: android, c++, linux, bitmap

I was surpized by the fact that JPEG codecs for CentOS Linux 6 and Android decode the same JPEG file to different bitmaps.

When I use `libjpeg` in C/C++ CentOS Linux application and `BitmapFactory` in Android one, some (many) pixels have different values for red, green or blue, or for all of them. The difference is usually 1 or 2, so it is complex or impossible to see the difference with eyes, however, if you generate some sort of hash of bitmap to identify this bitmap later, the hash value for Linux and Android will be different.

My question is: are there any way to set up `libjpeg` in such a way that it will decode JPEG file to the same bitmap as Android?

Comment: Even different processors might be involved, not only different lib (platform) versions. Best would be to do a similarity test: scale image down, round to nearest 4-fold or such. Especially on Android you do not want to do too much work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: no

You may not have realised but this is actually a philosophical question rather than a computer question.

Do you have any reason to believe that all Android systems on all Android platforms decode a JPEG to the same bitmap?

Or that even if they do, that they will continue to do so with codec updates or new Android releases, or even for all JPEGs?

There is no reason to believe that any solution that you may find today will still be a solution tomorrow, or will apply to all bitmaps.

The reason is that you do not control the Android codecs.

I suggest that you reconsider your reason for needing to do this.

Otherwise you might try to get the Android codec for the same CPU architecture and try it on your centos system, even run an Android system in a container on your centos system; but as I have warned you cannot expect it to solve your problem.